# How do I add all integers in one list to integers on another list with different length in the same order in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

Given:

`ListA = [1,2,3,4,5]`

`ListB = [10,20,30,40,50,60,70]`

How do I make it such that `ListC = [11,22,33,44,55,60,70]`, where `C[0] = B[0] + A[0]`... `C[5] = nil + B[5]` and so on? I can't simply use a for loop in this case as there will be an `IndexError` as `ListB` has two more entries as compared to `ListA?`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `itertools.zip_longest(..., fillvalue=0)`:

```
from itertools import zip_longest
[x + y for x, y in zip_longest(ListA, ListB, fillvalue=0)]
# [11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 60, 70]

# or in python 2
from itertools import izip_longest
[x + y for x, y in izip_longest(ListA, ListB, fillvalue=0)]
# [11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 60, 70]
```

If you prefer a numpy solution, you can use `numpy.pad` to pad the two lists to the same length:

```
import numpy as np

def add_np(A, B):
    m = max(len(A), len(B))
    return np.pad(A, (0, m-len(A)), 'constant') + np.pad(B, (0, m-len(B)), 'constant')

add_np(ListA, ListB)
# array([11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 60, 70])
```

Comment: Since this question is tagged `python 2.7` you should update the answer to use `izip_longest` instead of `zip_longest`

Answer (score 4):

Since you put the `numpy` tag:

```
C = np.array(ListB)
C[:len(ListA)] += ListA
C
# array([11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 60, 70])
```

If you don't know in advance which is the shorter and longer:

```
short, long_ = sorted([ListA, ListB], key=len)
C = np.array(long_)
C[:len(short)] += short
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a for loop, but you do have to account for the difference in length of lists. Add an if statement that checks that there exists an element at A[5], or whatever:

```
`
i = 0
for i in range(len(B)):
    if A[i]:
        C[i] = A[i] + B[i]
    else:
        C[i] = B[i]
`
```

Keep in mind this will only work in the sense you intend as long as you run the for loop on the longest list.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

First add those elements which are making pair and then remaining items :

```
ListA = [1,2,3,4,5]

ListB = [10,20,30,40,50,60,70]


your_data=list(map(lambda x,y:x+y,ListA,ListB))
your_data.extend(ListB[len(ListA):])
print(your_data)
```

output:

```
[11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 60, 70]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) to do this:

```
def zip_lists(l1, l2):
    if len(l1) == len(l2):
        return [x + y for x, y in zip(l1, l2)]

    s, b = min(l1, l2), max(l1, l2)

    rest = len(s)

    return [x + y for x, y in zip(s, b)] + b[rest:]
```

**Above logic**:

- If both lists have the same length, just `zip()` them normally.
- Otherwise, find the smallest list `s`, and the biggest list `b`.
- Compute the length of `s`, which is `rest`.
- Then `zip()` from both lists, and add on the trailing elements, `rest` from the bigger list `b`.

The behaviour of `zip_lists()` is shown below:

```
>>> print(zip_lists([1,2,3,4,5], [10,20,30,40,50,60,70]))
[11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 60, 70]
>>> print(zip_lists([1,2,3,4,5], [10,20,30,40,50]))
[11, 22, 33, 44, 55]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of the slicing operator.

```
op = sum
len_a, len_b = len(ListA), len(ListB)
min_len, max_len = min(len_a,len_b), max(len_a,len_b)
ListC = list(map(op,zip(ListA[:min_len],ListB[:min_len]))) + ListA[min_len:max_len] + ListB[min_len:max_len]
```

The last line will concatenate the remainder of the two lists.
If they are the same length then it won't do anything.
If they are not the same length then the `ListSmaller[min_len:max_len]` will be an empty list: `[]`